# How to find out which lib file I need to link while I use a third party library?

Tags: c++, cmake, target-link-libraries

For example if I use a function in opencv, and I can use two methods to specify the libs and link them.
First one, I can use `find_package(OpenCV 3.3 REQUIRED)`  and them `target_link_libraries( main  ${OpenCV_LIBS})` because the macro include all the libraries we need.
Second one, I want to link my opencv without ".cmake" and I need to give CMakeLists.txt a `link_directiories(/xxxx)` and use `target_link_libraries(main opencv_core opencv_imgcodecs)`.

So my question is how can I quickly find out which lib I should link while I use the second method. Like I use some function in the opencv_core.so but actually I know it by try several times among much libs in opencv.

Answer (score 0):

There is no quick way to do it, apart maybe from reading your library documentation. In OpenCV it is quite straightforward, [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/) specifies the list of the modules, then your rule of thumb should be: whenever you `#include <opencv2/MODULE_NAME.hpp>`, you link to `opencv_MODULE_NAME`. E.g. `#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>` , then you should link with `opencv_imgproc`.

If you don't have this kind of information beforehand, on the Linux machine you can investigate the symbols in the available dynamic libraries:

```
for lib in `find LIB_PATH -name "*.so"`; do echo ${lib}; nm -D -C ${lib}; done
```

where `LIB_PATH` is where your libraries are installed, e.g. `/usr/lib`.

You can then save the output and search for the undefined symbol that was reported by your linker while building your project. Instead of `"*.so"` you can have more restrictive pattern like `libopencv*.so` to limit the output.

Comment: Very appreciate. So there is no shortcut like grep key word in so(because it is binary type....). And opencv like you said, there is a hint in head file name. Thx again.

Comment: Well, of course you can grep the output of `nm -D -C` command. But not `cat libXXX.so` :)